# How to make TeXstudio be aware of defined variables?

Tags: texstudio

My LaTeX document consists of many `.tex` files distributed in a hierarchical directory structure. Something like this:

```
> myBook.tex
> myBook_structure.tex

> part1_Introduction
    |
    |--- Introduction_to_FreeRTOS
    |       |-- someFile.tex
    |       '-- someFile.tex
    |
    '--- How_to_use_FreeRTOS
            |-- someFile.tex
            '-- someFile.tex

> part2_FreeRTOS_examples
    |
    |--- First_example
    |       |-- someFile.tex
    |       '-- someFile.tex
    |
    '--- Second_Example
            |-- someFile.tex
            '-- someFile.tex
...
```

The `myBook_structure.tex` file keeps track of the overall project structure. I do this by defining directory paths:

```
    %% myBook_structure.tex
    %% --------------------
    \def\part1ch1{./part1_Introduction/Introduction_to_FreeRTOS}
    \def\part1ch2{./part1_Introduction/How_to_use_FreeRTOS}
    \def\part2ch1{./part2_FreeRTOS_examples/First_example}
    \def\part2ch2{./part2_FreeRTOS_examples/Second_example}
    ...
```

Now I can use these directory paths to include specific `.tex` files:

```
    %% myBook.tex
    %% -----------

    \input{./myBook_structure}
    ..
    \begin{document}
        ..
        %% Include a file from chapter 1 within part 1:
        \include{\part1ch1/someFile}
        %% Include a file from chapter 2 within part 1:
        \include{\part1ch2/someFile}
        ..
    \end{document}
```

This is very convenient. Imagine I change the directory name `Introduction_to_FreeRTOS` to `FreeRTOS_intro`. All I need to do is change one line in the `myBook_structure.tex` file:

```
    %% myBook_structure.tex
    %% --------------------
    \def\part1ch1{./part1_Introduction/FreeRTOS_intro} %% <- this line changed
    \def\part1ch2{./part1_Introduction/How_to_use_FreeRTOS}
    ... all other lines remain the same
```

It works perfectly. The project compiles without errors and delivers the pdf document as expected. Even in TeXstudio. I can simply click the 'compile' button, and it outputs the expected pdf document.

But there is one issue. TeXstudio gets a bit confused when showing the project tree on the left. TeXstudio doesn't expand the `\part1ch1` macros, and doesn't know where to look for the file. The project tree in the left margin of TeXstudio is now completely useless - I can no longer jump from one file to another.

[image]

How can I circumvent this problem, such that I can continue to use my favourite LaTeX IDE?

**EDIT:**

Apparently LaTeX doesn't accept a defined keyword that contains digits. So this is not accepted:

```
    \def\part1ch1{...}
```

But this is accepted:

```
    \def\myFirstChapter{...}  %% <- no digits in name 'myFirstChapter'
```

This unfortunate fact makes my plan to build a neat document structure even harder. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of digits, you could substitute letters -- `\partAchA` etc.  that should get you through unless you have more than 26 parts or 26 chapters.

Comment: That's a good idea :-)